# How would I move a SKSpriteNode in a certain direction?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to make a skspritenode move in a certain direction? As in degrees. EG: Face 70˚ then move in that direction. I am trying to make it so you can shoot a bullet from my player node but I cant figure out how to make the bullet go past where my mouse is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using physics, then you can applyImpulse using a CGVector. If you're not using physics then you would use an SKAction, but it doesn't solve your specific use. If you wanted to rotate the object first, then you'd change its zRotation. Obviously you'd have to setup the sprite and the physicsBody, but I've left those steps out.

```
SKSpriteNode *mySpriteToMove = [SKSpriteNode node];

[mySpriteToMove.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(floatDX, floatDY)];

[mySpriteToMove runAction:[SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(floatDX, floatDY) duration:amountOfTime]];

mySpriteToMove.zRotation = someValueInRadians;
```

CODE FOR COMMENT RESPONSE:

```
[mySpriteToMove runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(floatX, floatY) duration:amountOfTime]];
```

Comment: What if you don't know the specific coordinates, is their a way to calculate its path?

Comment: I've added the code. The developer docs apple provides for SKSprite and SKAction are great resources that are worth reading. The jumping into sprite kit page is a good place to start: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH2-SW1

Comment: You sir, are a genius thank you thank you thank you I find no way to fully convey my gratitude to you.